# Firebase para uma Lista

Tags: android, firebase, lista

Preciso pegar todos os dados do firebase e criar uma lista, para usar em um `listadaper` que criei.
Essa é a estrutura do Banco no Firebase:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como podem ver, quero pegar todos os `child` de Wallpapers(wallpaper1, wallpaper2, etc).

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
 DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Wallpapers").child("Wallpaper1");
```

E no value listener:

```
 ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            List<Wallpaper> list = new ArrayList<>();

            String Nome = (String) dataSnapshot.child("Nome").getValue();
            String Descricao = (String) dataSnapshot.child("Descricao").getValue();
            String URL = (String) dataSnapshot.child("URL").getValue();

            Wallpaper wallpaper = new Wallpaper(Nome, URL, Descricao);
            list.add(wallpaper);

            List_Adapter adapter = new List_Adapter(getApplicationContext(), list);
            lista_principal.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    };
    ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
}
```

Mas como tá meio óbvio, só tá pegando os itens de Wallpaper1;
O que preciso é que pegue todos os itens de Wallpapers e adicione numa Lista dessa classe:

```
public class Wallpaper {
private String Nome;
private String Url;
private String Descricao;

public Wallpaper(String nome, String url, String descricao) {
    Nome = nome;
    Url = url;
    Descricao = descricao;
}
```

pra eu poder usar ela no Listview adapter que criei.

Comment: Por que o banco está estruturado desse jeito? Se você tem uma lista de elementos do mesmo tipo, o ideal é usar um vetor. Fica mais fácil tanto para gravar quanto para recuperar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver fazendo o seguinte.
Removi o child de Wallpapers

```
 DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Wallpapers");
```

E fiz um foreach em cada Datasnapshot

```
for (DataSnapshot item : a) {
                String Nome = (String) item.child("Nome").getValue();
                String Descricao = (String) item.child("Descricao").getValue();
                String URL = (String) item.child("URL").getValue();
                Wallpaper wallpaper = new Wallpaper(Nome, URL, Descricao);

                list.add(wallpaper);
            }
```